# Rails: How to Test an Array's Order with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new to RSpec so I'm looking for a little help on a simple test:

```
# controller method
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @group_members = @group.group_members.order("posts ASC")
end

# in my rspec
it "should show order correctly" do
  @group = FactoryGirl.create(:group)
  @user_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_name: "Gary")
  @user_2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_name: "Shawn")
  @user_3 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_name: "Gus")
  @user_4 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_name: "Jack")
  @group_member_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:group_member, group_id: @group.id, user_id: @user_1.id, posts: 30)
  @group_member_2 = FactoryGirl.create(:group_member, group_id: @group.id, user_id: @user_2.id, posts: 20)
  @group_member_3 = FactoryGirl.create(:group_member, group_id: @group.id, user_id: @user_3.id, posts: 10)
  @group_member_4 = FactoryGirl.create(:group_member, group_id: @group.id, user_id: @user_4.id, posts: 15)
  visit group_path(@group)

  # how do i assert the order of the array?
end
```

Can someone please help me with a statement to check that the array sorted correctly?

Answer (score 4):

```
my_array.should eq expected_array
```

That will make sure that each item is in the exact same spot. If you want to check that an array has the same elements as another array, but the order doesn't matter, do this:

```
my_array.should =~ expected_array
```

So in your particular case, you first would need to do a `get` to the `show` action, then check the variable. That's done like this:

```
get :show, :id => @group.id
expected_group_members = [@group_member_3, @group_member_4, @group_member_2, @group_member_1]
assigns(:group_members).should eq expected_group_members
```

For more information, check out [RSpec's GitHub page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

Comment: Thanks @MrDanA.  For some reason when I used this code, I got (expected URI object or URI string).  When I use `visit_group_path(@group)`, along with the `expected...` and `assigns...` lines, I get the error `undefined method 'view_assigns' for nil:NilClass'.  I don't understand because when I use `save_and_open_page` I see that the array results show on the view.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note the matchers [`match_array`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:match_array) and [`contain_exactly`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:contain_exactly) should be used in RSpec 3 instead of `should =~`.

Comment: @Dennis those seem to not respect order, which was part of the question. How to test an array and be explicit about order?